# Hosting websites with different portnumbers in ASP.Net IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web, localhost

I have just begin using ASP.Net Web application in Visual Studio. What I want to know is that I have two web pages namely index1.aspx and index2.aspx. I want to host them separately using different port numbers in local host on the iis server. I know site binding is used in these cases but not sure how to go about it.
What is the best way to do this? I want them to run simultaneously and communicate between each other.

Comment: Put them in separate projects in your solution.  Then right-click on the solution and select "Set Start Up Projects" and choose both of them.  Then when you compile and run, both applications should start on their own ports.

Comment: @David  hard to know if He means in development or production

Comment: @KeithNicholas: I guess "local host" implies development to me.  For deploying to any server, production or otherwise, that's an entirely different story and depends on whatever the OP's current deployment strategy is.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by different projects in one solution. As far as I know, I'm developing a solution within one project @David

Comment: @the_coder_in_me: You can't have Visual Studio solutions *within a project*.  A solution is a container for projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS there is something called Virtual directory. You can create two web applications in IIS and make both pointing to same physical location on your system.

You can also update settings of each web application to have different index pages. i.e. web app1 shall use Index1.aspx as index page, and web app 2 shall use Index2.aspx.

Virtual directories are so cool, you can use the same code base for multiple tenants. All we have to create is new web apps or sites in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it like this:
I created two projects WebApp1 and WebApp2 in the same Solution.

Right Click on Solution Explorer--> Properties--->Select the radio button with Multiple Startup projects.
Also make sure The Action of atleast one of the projects is set to Start only . The rest can be Start Without Debugging.

To connect IIS to your web application say webapp1:
Reference this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwbKquNBNgQ

Hope this helps anyone who is trying this out.